# Meteoric: Meteor + Ionic Demo App

Tags: javascript, meteor, sass, ionic-framework, meteoric

I have started to read more about Meteor for Mobile App Development.

Some people say Meteoric (Meteor + Ionic) is one of the best solutions to achieve the end result of having a good Mobile Meteor App.

I have therefore gone to the website and download the demo app of Meteoric from: https://github.com/meteoric/demo

So I downloaded the demo app and tried to start the app using the `meteor` command inside the project folder.

However, I get this error that I don't know how to fix:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While building the application:
   /Users/bliss/Downloads/demo-master/client/stylesheets/app.scss:4:9: Scss compiler error: file to import not found or unreadable:
   .meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/ionic
   Current dir: /Users/bliss/Downloads/demo-master/client/stylesheets/
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Thank you very much....

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error when installing on windows 32-bit machine. I just updated the meteor using

```
meteor update
```

And now everything runs fine!!

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that several meteor packages throw the first time you run an app that uses them.

All that is required is to stop (ctrl-c) and restart the meteor server and it will find all the resources it requires.

[Reference:](https://github.com/meteoric/ionic-sass)

> NOTE: Due to a current limitation of the Meteor packaging system, the
>   above path may not exist the first time you run your Meteor app after
>   installing this package. This will cause an error saying the file to
>   import was not found. This may also occur if you run meteor reset.
>   Restarting your app should fix this problem. See meteor/meteor#2606
>   and meteor/meteor#2796 for more info.